# UITextField placeholder tail truncation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

Please help truncating the placeholder of a `UITextField` like it does the `UILabel` with `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`.

I would post some code, but.. there's nothing to post... I don't even know what to start trying.

There's no problem with tail truncation of a label, but the placeholder of the textfield... no idea.

What's the use:

The placeholder has to list some cities:

```
"Search in Munchen, Stanberg, Frankfurt, Blablabla"
```

The textfield truncates its placeholder to:

`"Search in Munchen, Stanberg, Frankfurt,"` ( notice the last comma )

I gotta do it like this:

```
"Search in Munchen, Stanberg, Frankfurt, Bla..."
```

Even if I somehow delete the "last" comma, I need the rest "Bla...", in order to suggest the user that the list is not finished with Frankfurt.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot truncate with the existing methods, however in the delegate method you can check for the limit and then append "...".

Comment: What's the use of it if the user can't read it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom `UITextField` subclass and override method `- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect`

Something like this

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:1.0] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There's an `attributedPlaceholder` property of `UITextField` that you should be able to modify to have the desired truncation logic.